# PHP doesn't receive data from html form

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', '"'
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

I am trying to insert data from html form to database and I am getting an error

```
$sql="INSERT INTO shooting VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]"', '".$_POST["date"]"', '".$_POST["time"]"', '".$_POST["status"]')";
```

Comment: You are missing `.` dot 4 dot.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score -2):

Hi there is issue in your syntax kindly check below.

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO shooting VALUES ('".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["date"]."', '".$_POST["time"]."', '".$_POST["status"]."')";
```

And you should use `mysql_real_escape_string` method to prevent SQL injection.

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);
```

And insert `$date` variable in database.

Comment: Should be using `mysqli_*`. Any `mysql_*` has long been deprecated and completely removed PHP 7+

Comment: There would be many suggestion but straight forward there is missing `.` dot

Comment: @ Francisco Mateo i just suggested. There is lot of ways for it. So you don't have to rights to down vote my answer if there is not useful then you can down vote otherwise stay same.

Comment: @devraj : I down voted because this doesn't help to solve the problem.

Comment: @ C2486  May i know what is issue in my answer?